# How to configure Separate Domain registrar, Web host and Email host settings?

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, dns-hosting

Let's say we have a domain **example.com**

1. Domain registrar : NAME.COM
2. Web Host : IPAGE.COM
3. Email Host : GMAIL (Google Apps)

My understanding is that:

- I should add MX records to use Gmail (clear)
- I must add A record to use Ipage hosting (clear)

What should be the Nameserver values? Should I keep the nameserver values of NAME.COM or change them to IPAGE nameserver values? And is it necessary to change nameservers?

UPDATE: I wanna make everything clear before I make actual changes.

Comment: The NS records should be pointing at the same DNS servers that you've configured with your registrar, i.e. the DNS servers that host the data for your domain. I suspect you're confused by why you're having to define this in two separate locations, so I'm flagging this as a duplicate of a Q&A explaining this from a technical standpoint.

Answer (score 1):

After not finding a satisfactory answer I gave try to the concepts already mentioned in the question:

1. I set MX records to Gmail (Google Apps)
2. I set A record to Ipage (Where website is hosted)

But to do that, I first had to set Nameservers to default nameservers of Name.com

Now my:

1. DNS host is name.com
2. Website host ipage.com
3. Email server Gmail (Google apps)

And everything is working like a charm.